# mysql how to extract row with max value within a group

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume a database:

```
name   |group   |age
---------------------
aron    1        1
bob     1        2
charlie 2        3
danny   2        4
eugene  3        5
null    4        0
```

how to achieve a query which would extract

```
name   |group   |age
---------------------
bob     1        2
danny   2        4
eugene  3        5
null    4        0
```

which would pick the person with the greatest age within each group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use join like below. Note that this will bring more than 1 rows from a group if more than 1 have maximum age

```
select A.* from yourtable A
inner join (
select `group`, max(age) as age from 
yourtable 
group by `group`
)B
on A.age=B.age and A.`group`=B.`group`
```

alternately you can also use rank() like

```
select name, age, `group` 
from 
(
 select name,age,`group`, RANK() OVER (partition by `group` order by age desc) as rank from 
    yourtable 
) T where T.rank=1
```

Comment: The column name `group` conflicts with its keyword counterpart. Consider embracing it with backticks : )